# Anyone made stackoverflow data available as a Windows Help File?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Wondering if anyone has attempted to load the stackoverflow data into one of those compiled windows help files? I have always liked those. Just wondering if it has already been done.

Comment: That would be one *massive* CHM file. I can't imagine it would perform well... Heck, the small ones aren't exactly *speedy*.

Comment: I want a man page!

Comment: Isn't .CHM deprecated? Seems a lot of effort for a file format Microsoft doesn't even want around anymore.

Comment: CHM deprecated? Maybe, but aren't there clones? Don't people still use them?

man page! har. I would vote for a chm file instead of my man pages.

massive chm file...yes thought of that, you would probably want to limit it somehow, perhaps one language, questions with certain attributes, what have you.

a lot of work...well hoping this would be pretty much automated, never built a chm file myself but I imagine the work would be upfront and reusable for other things in the future, I can see other uses for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one has posted it, you could do it yourself and then make it available for the rest.

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for. Thanks.